# Does booting from a linux live distro leave any trace in a windows hard disk that it mounts?

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, boot

Background: at work I have a Windows 7 PC where I only have normal user privileges. The PC can boot from CD o USB. I **suspect** that one of my colleagues is, from time to time, booting my PC with a Linux live distribution, mounting the Windows disk and copying and occasionally deleting files from it (from my user directory), but I have no proof.

It would help me if I could somehow prove that somebody has being tampering with it, but I have no clue on how t do it. Something like showing a log of booting, or access to files at some time I am not present would be enough.

Is there anyway to accomplish that, or booting from a live Linux doesn't lave traces?

**EDIT: based on the comments posted:**

- My knowledge of computers is rather basic
- Hibernation and suspension are disabled and I can't change that
- I can't report to IT department or to our boss without "something" to show them; my suspicions aren't enough reason

Comment: I've not used it, but it looks as though the [USN Journal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USN_Journal) will give you this information. Moreover, if you hibernate instead of doing a full shut-down, volumes mounted in Windows will be locked and inaccessible from a Linux Live boot: this should protect you from tampering.

Comment: @AFH Thanks for the reply - I should have mentioned that I'm not computer savy, so no idea on how to Access the USN Journal. Also, hibernation and suspensión are disabled and without Admin privileges I cannot change the policy

Comment: just report it to your IT dept and ask them to inspect your pc and disable CD/USB booting if possible. not your personal pc, not your problem to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If booting from a live CD, the NTFS partitions of the hard disk can be mounted R/O (or with the `noatime` to avoid updating the access times). The person with the Live CD can also do a physical copy of the drive or some partition to an external disk for further study.

Preventing booting from USB in the BIOS (assuming the BIOS is password-protected) in only part of the answer: if the PC can be opened, the disk can be removed and inserted in a SATA-to-USB converter connected to another PC.

So a knowledgeable attacker won't leave visible clues in the filesystem itself.

If physical access is possible, the only real way to protect the disk content from snooping or tampering is to encrypt it.

Now, if the disk is recent it normally supports [SMART diagnostics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)(disks that don't support them are normally out of commission by now or your company is very, very poor), and SMART diagnostics include some statistics data that can only increase with usage (power-on time, power cycle count...) and since it requires very expensive machinery to read your disk contents without powering it up, a snooper would always increase these values. So, using a SMART diags utility, you could note these down before powering off and check them again right after boot, and figure out if the difference can only be explained by extraneous activity.

Comment: If I understand correctly, if the hard disk is mounted read-write without the *noatime* parameter, the access times are updated. And another way to detect the access would be via a SMART diagnostics utility. Thus 2 potential ways to find evidence of access ! Thanks

Comment: You understood correctly.